# Problème avec les modèles de reçu fiscal suite migtation Civi

Tags: civicontribute, civimail, civireport

Bonjour

Dans notre precedant modèle de reçu fiscal, les champs de fusion {contribution.total_amount}, {contribution.payment_instrument}, {contribution.payment_number}, {contribution.receive_date} étaient utilisées.
Depuis la mise en place de la dernière version du logiciel, ces champs ne sont plus valorisés.
Quels sont maintenant les champs de fusion correspondant.

[image]

Bien cordialement
Philippe ROLLAND
Bretagne Vivante

Comment: Ces champs devraient fonctionner, n'ont pas changé. Est-ce-que il y a erreurs enregistrée?

Comment: Bonjour 

Voici l'erreur que j'ai obtenue lors de l'utilisation des anciens modèles :   "Le champ de fusion {contribution.payment_instrument} n'est plus maintenu - utilisez {contribution.payment_instrument_id:label} à la place. Ce que j'ai fait.  Merci de votre aide. PR

Comment: Bonjour. Ou puis je trouver les informations/définitions concernant les champs de fusion en particulier du module contribution.
PR

Comment: Tous ceux que vous pouvez voir dans le API Explorer - Contribution - Get dans le champ Select (sauf ceux en lettres gras) sont disponibles. Aussi tous de {contribution_recur_id.XXXXX} y quelques de {contribution_page_id. XXXX} ('frontend_title', 'pay_later_text', 'pay_later_receipt', 'is_share', 'receipt_text').